# FileInputStream issue for Android

Tags: android, string, fileinputstream

I am new to ADK. Recently I wrote a program to get strings from
    other devices. It's OK except for Chinese string. Can anyone
    help to fix this problem?

```
my codes look like this
mFileDescriptor = mUsbManager.openAccessory(mAccessory);

FileDescriptor fd = mFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();

mInputStream = new FileInputStream(fd);

byte[] b = new byte[512];
int n;
String str;

while ((n = mInputStream.read(b)) != -1) 
{
......
str = (new String(b, 0, n, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Chinese language is represented in Unicode as multi-byte characters. So, to read it properly, you need to use specific reader objects which can understand and interpret the multi-byte character encoding concept.

Essentially, you need to do something like this:

```
try {
    BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(inputstream,Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    String line = null;
    while ((line= bufReader.readLine())!= null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I've modified it but still not work. Is anything I get wrong? mFileDescriptor = mUsbManager.openAccessory(mAccessory);

if (mFileDescriptor != null) 
{
FileDescriptor fd = mFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();

mInputStream = new FileInputStream(fd);
BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mInputStream,Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
while ((str= bufReader.readLine())!= null) 
{
}

Comment: Ah, I see that you are dealing with USB accessories using AOA. Well, there are some issues waiting for you with that InputStream from UsbManager. Although this stream is somewhat in conformance with JAVA specifications for stream objects, as far as my experience goes, it is in some ways not a normal InputStream object wrapping a normal disk file.  Please try writing the data you are reading from that input stream to a file first and once you have a considerable amount of data in the file, try to read the file using the methods above.

Comment: thanks so much for your help. I will try to write the strings to file first.